# Numba CUDA: Compilation error while trying to make a dot product + comparation

Tags: python-3.x, cuda, numba

I'm very new to numba.cuda and the following code does not work. Was hoping you could identify the reason

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

random_points = np.random.uniform(0, 6, (1000, 2))
result = np.full(random_points.shape[0], True)
hull = ConvexHull(np.array([(1, 2), (3, 4), (3, 6), (2, 4.5), (2.5, 5)]))

@cuda.jit
def my_kernel(points, eq, result):
    pos = cuda.grid(1)

    if pos < points.shape[0]:
        for i in range(eq.shape[0]):
            temp = 0.
            for j in range(points.shape[1]):
                temp += eq[i,j]*points[pos,j]
            temp += eq[i,-1]
            if temp > 1e-12:
                result[pos] = False
    

# Host code   
threadsperblock = 256
blockspergrid = int(np.ceil(random_points.shape[0] / threadsperblock))
my_kernel[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](random_points, hull.equations, result)
print(result)
```

Error:
NvvmError: Failed to compile

```
<unnamed> (35, 32): parse expected comma after getelementptr's type
NVVM_ERROR_COMPILATION
```

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Alright ill edit the question and add a guard for that, which i'm guessing happens when the cuda grid is higher than the length of result

Comment: I still can't reproduce the error with `numba 0.56.0` and `cuda 11.2`. The kernel works as intended.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Well that is great news! I just tested using your version and you are right. I do get some new warnings but the output is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine, it's just the version of numba/cudatoolkit.
@MichaelSzczesny tried it with `numba 0.56.0` and `cuda 11.2`and it worked, so thanks to him!

Version that did NOT work: `numba 0.45.1` & `cudatoolkit 11.3.1`, installed through conda